# Displaying blank page when including php-mysql connection file

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, lamp

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I am using lamp. I had a more complex issue but I figured out what is causing the error and made a small php-mysql connection snippet. When the connection file is included into the php/html file the whole thing displays a blank page.

My connect.php code:

```
  <?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "ecalendar";
$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);
if(mysqli_connect_errno(){
    echo "Error".mysqli_connect_errno();
}

?>
```

and my web page with connection file included:

```
    <?php
include "connect.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Testing</p>
        <?php
            $sql="SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventid=1";
            $result = mysqli_query($sql);

        ?>
        <ul>
            <li><?php $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                echo $result;

             ?>
            </li>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Check your Apache logs.

Comment: Could you turn error reporting on ?

Comment: [Turn error reporting on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) so that you can see a description of what's wrong. If you still can't solve the issue after reading the error, post the error message here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line in `connect.php`:

```
if(mysqli_connect_errno(){
```

Should be:

```
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){ // note the extra ')'
```

You were not properly enclosing your condition with `()`.

Comment: Thanks D4V1D now the page is displaying but still the database record isn't displaying in the page

Comment: So your question has been resolved. You should ask another one and, in the meantime, accept the one that solves your problem. Also, try `echo`ing `$row` instead of `$result`.

Comment: Thanks D4VID. The $row didn't work. I'll search on that. Yes my question has been resolved

Comment: @D4V1D problem in this line `<?php $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                echo $result;

             ?>` OP is try to echo `$result` instead `print_r($row);`